# Finding the probability that x is between 2 values

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am trying to find the probability that x is greater than 6, but less than 14.

I know that the probability of x being greater than 6 is 0.9095, and the probability that x being less than 16 is 0.8360.

How can I use this information to answer the question?

I thought that it could be attained by dividing 0.9095 by 0.8360, but this gives an answer greater than one.

Comment: Let $A$ denote the event that $x>6$ and let $B$ denote the event that $x<16$.  The given information is $Pr(A)=0.9095$ and $Pr(B)=0.8360$.  You wish to find $Pr(A\cup B)$.  This expands via inclusion-exclusion as $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cup B)$.  Now... you should be able to figure out $Pr(A\cup B)$, the probability that $x$ is greater than $6$ *or* less than $16$ (*every real number is greater than 6 or less than 16, so the probability is...*) and finally plugging in the appropriate numbers you get...

Comment: JMoravitz Thank you. We haven't yet been taught expanding via inclusion or exclusion, do you think we would just be expected to do: P(x=10) + P(x=11) ..... + P(x=15) ?

Comment: I hate to say that it is the only available method, but it really kind of is... That being said, inclusion-exclusion is fundamental and should be included in  the first chapter of any introduction to probability so I cannot believe that you haven't been exposed to it yet.  Approaching like you suggest in the comment cannot be the intended solution as it isn't even given that the distribution is discrete, not to mention there is not nearly enough information to determine those values even if it were.

Comment: Can it be that there is a typo in your question and there should be either "less than 14" or "less than 16" but not both?
Then you could solve it immediately with the tools you have as:
$P(6<X<1?) = P(x<1?) - P(X<=6) = 0.8360 - (1-P(X>6)) =0.8360 - 1 + 0.9095=0.7455$